# phantomjs pdf clickable hyperlink

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I have been trying to get clickable hyperlinks in PDFs after using rasterize.js with phantomjs. I have found one comment on the phantomjs code.google.com page that says that hyperlinks are supported, but no examples of it working. I also tried the example from the quickstart guide at http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart

Has anyone else gotten this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug right now that you can find details on here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10196.  Ideally the links would work but they don't right now.

Comment: It's supposed to work since 2.1 but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if links are "clickable" using PhantomJS' PDF rasterizing. I think it just saves an image of the page to a PDF. According to the API docs, it saves the image buffer of the web page: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture

Comment: Text is saved like text and not image. just open your rendered file and to make sure save it as Text (Plain). You'll see the links as a part of the file. Or in your js you can see them in output using
console.log(page.plainText);